# Is there any librtmp c# .net wrapper?

Tags: c#, .net, c, wrapper, rtmp

Is there any librtmp c# .net wrapper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want librtmp wrpaper? Can't you just use a [.NET RTMP library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319378/rtmp-c-client-library)?

Comment: I need a server - not Client library.