# Librtmp .net wrapper / rtmpdump with fluorinefx?

Tags: c#, .net, rtmp

Ive read the posts: "[.Net libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319378/rtmp-c-client-library)" and "[why use a wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382067/is-there-any-librtmp-c-net-wrapper)".

When using rtmpdump i am able to get all the fields and dump a rtmp stream successfully...but im not sure how to replicate this using [fluorinefx](http://www.fluorinefx.com). I'm having a hard time locating some fluorinefx tutorials/samples other than they ones they provide with do not help in the direction as to "dumping the stream".

Maybe there are other librarys that would be more useful to me?

Does anyone have some more insight on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can dump the rtmp stream successfully, I'm not sure that this is a C#/.Net or rtmp question as your tags indicate.  This sounds like a limitation of flourinefx.  Even someone well versed in C#, .Net and rtmp won't be able to give you much guidance on something like this.

Have you contacted "the silent group" (the creators of flourinefx) with your question?